# Using Dice metric in pytorch "torchmetrics" : dice_score() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'preds' and 'target'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to use Dice metric from pytorch "torchmetrics". I found an example for using accuracy metric. like below :

```
from torchmetrics.classification import Accuracy

train_accuracy = Accuracy()
valid_accuracy = Accuracy()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for x, y in train_data:
        y_hat = model(x)

        # training step accuracy
        batch_acc = train_accuracy(y_hat, y)
        print(f"Accuracy of batch{i} is {batch_acc}")

    for x, y in valid_data:
        y_hat = model(x)
        valid_accuracy.update(y_hat, y)

    # total accuracy over all training batches
    total_train_accuracy = train_accuracy.compute()

    # total accuracy over all validation batches
    total_valid_accuracy = valid_accuracy.compute()

    print(f"Training acc for epoch {epoch}: {total_train_accuracy}")
    print(f"Validation acc for epoch {epoch}: {total_valid_accuracy}")

    # Reset metric states after each epoch
    train_accuracy.reset()
    valid_accuracy.reset()
```

However, when I replaced "Accuracy()"  with "Dice_score()". like below:

```
from torchmetrics.functional import dice_score

train_accuracy =dice_score()
valid_accuracy =dice_score()
```

I got below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-726045592283> in <module>
      3 from torchmetrics.functional import dice_score
      4 
----> 5 train_accuracy_2 =dice_score()# Accuracy()
      6 valid_accuracy_2 =dice_score()# Accuracy()
      7 

TypeError: dice_score() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'preds' and 'target'
```

Is there an example of using **"Dice"** metric from **"torchmetrics"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`torchmetrics.classification.dice_score`](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/dice_score.html) is the functional interface to the Dice score. That means it is a stateless function that expects the ground truth and predictions. There doesn't seem to be a module interface to the Dice score, like there is with accuracy.

[`torchmetrics.classification.Accuracy`](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/accuracy.html) is a class that maintains state. Under the hood, it uses the functional interface, which is [`torchmetrics.functional.accuracy`](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/accuracy.html#functional-interface).

This is not enforced in any way, but typically classes are named with CamelCase and functions are named with snake_case.

Comment: Thank you ... I notice also there is KLDivergence, hinge and JaccardIndex. Could any of those used as Dice?

Comment: No, those are not equivalent to Dice. F1 score is the same as Dice. Jaccard is similar to Dice but not quite the same.